# Using private docker images in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerhub

I have tried following the documentation on this link :

```
<https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private>
```

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-alami
```

My .dockercfg file looks something like this:

```
{
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/" :
    {
      "auth" : "username:pwd [base 64 enc]",
      "email" : "email_id"
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to pull a private image from Docker hub and my Dockerrun.aws.json looks something like this :

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "my-bucket",
    "Key": ".dockercfg"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "dishvy/imgname:tag",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

I have added the dockercfg file at the root of the bucket. And when i'm trying to deploy this to AWS Beanstalk, I get this error :

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for dishvy/imgname:tag, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

This essentially means my authentication file on S3 isn't correct but i followed the steps given in documentation and can't figure out where i went wrong. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem somewhat by shifting to ECR and pulling images from there. I went for this option after taking help from AWS Support and even they weren't able to help me with the problem I faced with pulling images from Dockerhub.